# Communicate interview preparation

Tags: interviewing, technology

I have an upcoming technology related job interview this week and I would like to speak with my recruiter about preparation. I reached out and my recruiter told me about the rounds and their nature (technical, problem solving etc) but was not specific enough.
How do I ask them about interview agenda and focus in such a way  that will help me with a detailed answer? I know this is allowed because in past my recruiters have helped me immensely with specifics, what to study, what to focus, prep for etc.
Can someone help?

Comment: Why don't you just ask them for as much information that they can provide. It's in their interests for you to get the job.

Answer (score 4):

You can ask them directly.

Many recruitment agents ask candidates after their interviews how it went and what was covered.  They use this to help the next candidate.

A simple phone call with a question like "I was preparing for the interview with X company, do you know if they prefer candidates with specific knowledge in certain areas?" should get the ball rolling.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot by the recruiter.  Some recruiters take additional steps to prep their clients for interviews, and they take feedback from other applicants regarding what was asked, how to answer, and so on.  Other recruiters don't even have the slightest idea how the interview process works and give you some generic form answer when you ask about it.  The best you can do is ask and try to get whatever info you can, but it's possible they simply don't know enough to speak intelligently on the subject.